# iPhone - Page loading time in webview

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, iphone

Using the Safari developer tools option, i can connect my iphone to MAC machine and see the loading time of each of the components ( of my iphone safari browser page ) in my MAC Safari application.

But, to get the same component level detail for the webview component inside any application (debug build), i need developer provisioning profile.

I have only testing provisioning profile. So, i could download the app into my device and connect to instruments But in Safari developer option, i dont see my application.

From this, i assume that testing provisioning profile is not sufficient and i need developer provisioning profile to debug my web view component in any application.

Please confirm if my understanding is correct ?

My question is - Is it mandatory to have developer provisioning profile installed in device to get component loading time from web view ? or is Testing provisioning profile sufficient ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this link,
[Apple developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent/DebuggingSafarioniPhoneContent.html)

The following line says that,

> If you have a development provisioning profile installed on your device, you can debug any web view (UIWebView object) in your app. This is particularly useful if your app manipulates the DOM in any way, and you want to observe the generated markup.

based on this, i assume that my assumption is correct. If anybody has any other opinion kindly mention the same. Thanks.